# Using momentjs, how can I find which weekday number a specific day is in a month, and how many of a weekday are in a given month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using momentjs, how can I find which weekday number a specific day is in a month, and how many of a weekday are in a given month?

Given any date, I need to extract if it is the First, Second, etc 'Saturday' of a specified month. Additionally, I need to know how many 'Saturdays' are in a given month. 'Saturday' is only an example. I will have a single date as my starting point of reference, and whatever date that is, I need the above stats on the Day of Week.

I started down the path of creating a second moment() and moving the week of the second object and comparing month names... but I want to do this using the momentjs native methods if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer provided by dave is very good but needs a small modification:

```
Math.floor(DAYS_IN_MONTH / 7) + ((DAYS_IN_MONTH % 7 >= ((X - 1) % 7) + 1) ? 1 : 0)
```

Without this modification the formula incorrectly calculates the value for the weekday that falls on the 7th day of the month. For example, in a February with 28 days and the 7th day being a Monday, the original formula will calculate that there are 5 Mondays when in fact there are 4. The updated formula will correctly calculate that there are 4 Mondays.

Original:

```
Math.floor(28 / 7) + ((28 % 7 >= 7 % 7) ? 1 : 0) =
4 + ((0 >= 0) ? 1 : 0) =
4 + (true ? 1 : 0) =
4 + 1 =
5
```

Updated:

```
Math.floor(28 / 7) + ((28 % 7 >= ((7 - 1) % 7) + 1) ? 1 : 0) =
4 + ((0 >= (6 % 7) + 1) ? 1 : 0) =
4 + ((0 >= 6 + 1) ? 1 : 0) =
4 + ((0 >= 7) ? 1 : 0) =
4 + (false ? 1 : 0) =
4 + 0 =
4
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as you know the date you are working with, and the number of days in that month, everything else is pretty simple.

If you know it's a Saturday, and you know it's the `X`th day of the month, then you also know it is the `Math.ceil(X/7)`'th Saturday of the month.

Now, if you know there are `DAYS_IN_MONTH` days in the month, and you know a Saturday falls on the `X`th day of the month, then you also know there are `Math.floor(DAYS_IN_MONTH/7) + (DAYS_IN_MONTH%7 >= X%7 ? 1 : 0)` days.